# How can I find the result of $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n)}{n(n+1)} $ without computationally evaluating it

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Good morning,

recently in a school near mine there was a contest for solving a infinite series that even professors couldn't, only thing we knew was the final result, approximately 0.118272222745.

The infinite series was this:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n)}{n(n+1)} $$

I'm trying to find a closed-form expression for this series, if it exists. Has anyone come across a series like this or have any insights on how to approach it and eventually solve it?

Comment: *Hint*. The real part of a complex power series using $\cos(n) = \operatorname{Re}(e^{in})$.

Comment: you can see the closed form by entering the series directly into WolframAlpha; it shows you just how complicated it is! [**Link**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+n%3D1+to+infinity+of+cos%28n%29%2F%28n%28n%2B1%29%29).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{x^n}}}{{n\left( {n + 1} \right)}} = \frac{{\ln \left( {1 - x} \right)}}{x} - \ln \left( {1 - x} \right) + 1}   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\cos \left( n \right)}}{{n\left( {n + 1} \right)}} = \Re \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{in}}}}{{n\left( {n + 1} \right)}} = \Re } } \left( {\frac{{\ln \left( {1 - {e^i}} \right)}}{{{e^i}}} - \ln \left( {1 - {e^i}} \right) + 1} \right)  \cr 
  &  = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\sin \left( 1 \right) - \frac{1}{2}\pi \sin \left( 1 \right) - \frac{1}{2}\ln \left( {2 - 2\cos \left( 1 \right)} \right) + \frac{1}{2}\cos \left( 1 \right)\ln \left( {2 - 2\cos \left( 1 \right)} \right)  \cr 
  &  = 1 + \frac{1}{2}\sin \left( 1 \right)\left( {1 - \pi } \right) - {\sin ^2}\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)\ln \left( {2 - 2\cos \left( 1 \right)} \right) \cr} $$

Comment: This gives the right answer. I don't understand who would downvote this.

Comment: @KamalSaleh Strange! +1

Comment: yup! This is the right one!